# Assign TForm to a variable Delphi to be used in other units

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have an application with three forms (one for phone, tablet and desktop) that all have the same component and all components have the same name on each form. Only one form gets created when the application starts depending on the screen solution.

I then have a unit that is called from the forms unit and I need to display the result on the calling form/unit

Right now I have to do this:

```
If assigned(mobileform1) do
   mobileform1.Memo1.Text := MyText
else if assigned(mobileform2) do
   mobileform1.Memo1.Text := MyText
else if assigned(desktopform) do
   mobileform1.Memo1.Text := MyText;
```

Is there a way to assign the Form that get created to an variable and just have one line?

```
CreatedForm.Memo1.Text := MyText;
```

I tried to assign it to a TForm Variable, but I can't use it or I don't know how.

Thanks,
for any help.

Comment: Is this a copy/paste error, all branches assign to `mobileform1.Memo1.Text` ? If not, your solution is to remove the "if".

Comment: Lots of ways to solve this. Perhaps you could just have one form and lay it out differently depending on the target. Or hide the form implementation behind an interface. Probably not enough information here for anyone to give definitive advice.

Comment: Anyway, I think you won't communicate. At this level, the solution is to use a base form. Descend all your front end forms from a form that has a Memo1 and use a variable of the type of that form.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, the proper solution to your problem is to use a **base form**.

In the meantime, this should give you a quick solution to your problem:

```
  (CreatedForm . FindComponent ( 'Memo1' ) as tMemo)
     . Text := 'I love peanut butter sandwiches.';
```

Why doesn't it work to refer to `CreatedForm.Memo1`? Consider the following code:

```
type
  tMyBaseClass = class
    X : double;
  end;

  tClassA = class ( tMyBaseClass )
    Y : integer;
    Z : string;
  end;

  tClassB = class ( tMyBaseClass )
    Y : array[1..100]of integer;
    Z : string;
  end;

var
  J : tClassA;
  K : tMyBaseClass;
begin
  J := tClassA . Create;
  J . X := 3.14;
  J . Y := 4;
  J . Z := 'Hello';

  K := J;
  K . X := 2.71828;
  K . Y := 7;       // Does not compile
  K . Z := 'There'; // Does not compile
```

We start by defining a base class, `tMyBaseClass`, and we define two different class types that are derived from `tMyBaseClass`, `tClassA` and `tClassB`.
`J` is declared as type `tClassA`.  The compiler knows that `J` refers to an instance of a `tClassA` object, and therefore you can access `J.X`, `J.Y`, and `J.Z`.  But `K` is of type `tMyBaseClass`.  You can refer to `K.X` because it is defined in the base class, but you can't access `K.Y` or `K.Z` because those are fields of `tClassA`, and the compiler can't know that `K` is referring to an instance of `tClassA`.

This is essentially what's going on in your code.  The base class is `tForm`, and you've defined class `tMobileForm` and `tDesktopForm` which are both derived from `tForm`.  Each of those forms has a field named `Memo1`.  You have `CreatedForm` which is of type `tForm`.  You can't access `CreatedForm.Memo1` because the `tForm` class does not have a field named `Memo1`.

One solution is to move the `Memo1` field into a base class.  So you could have

```
type
  tSharedForm = class ( tForm )
    Memo1 : tMemo;
  end;

  tDesktopForm = class ( tSharedForm )
    SomeOtherControl : tPanel;
  end;

  tMobileForm = class ( tSharedForm )
    SomeOtherControl : tComboBox;
  end;
```

If you then declare `CreatedForm` to be of type `tSharedForm`, then you can access `CreatedForm.Memo1` since it is now in the base class.

This is what a **base form** will do for you.

Comment: Thanks, so I will create form tSharedForm and add all the component that I need to access to that form. Then I create the other forms using class tSharedForm instead of TForm? So all procedure on each Form like onclick would I have to move them to the tSharedform?

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to find an online tutorial that will teach you about creating a base form.   My answer is meant to be an introduction to the concept in the most general terms.

Comment: Thanks, To many errors when I make the base form. OnClick do not work. Went back to If assigned.

Comment: At the beginning of my answer, I give you an alternative, using FindComponent.  Is this useful to you?